# How to create groups in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I need to create group in my signalR hub but the Context.ConnectionId line is null:

```
public class MetricHub : Hub
    {
        public MetricHub()
        {
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Syslog");
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Heatmap");
        }
    }
```

and this is the backgroundTicker class which uses MetricHub class:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Makbin.Data;
using Makbin.Web.Model;
using Makbin.Web.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace Makbin.Web.Hubs
{
    public class test
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    public class BackgroundTicker : IRegisteredObject
    {

        private readonly MakbinRepository _repository;
        private Timer devicesTimer;
        private IHubContext hub;



        public BackgroundTicker()
        {

            _repository = new MakbinRepository();

            HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

            hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MetricHub>();           



            devicesTimer = new Timer(OnDevicesTimerElapsed, null,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }


        private void OnDevicesTimerElapsed(object sender)
        {

            var result = _repository.Peripherals.Select(x => new { x.PeripheralId, x.Severity });
            var finalResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None,
                        new JsonSerializerSettings()
                        {
                            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                        });

            hub.Clients.Group("Heatmap").broadcastMessage(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(), finalResult);
        }

        public void Stop(bool immediate)
        {
            //deviceDetailTimer.Dispose();
            devicesTimer.Dispose();

            HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My purpose from this code is to define groups before sending any data.
Here I have defined two groups: Syslog, Heatmap. Besides, my connection to the client is one-way (server to client).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to map signalR (after configuring authentication) in the `Configuration` function :

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed i user
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index")
    });

   ...


    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Getting start with signalR :

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: I don't have any authentication part in my project, is it important to have authentication?

Comment: It's not mandatory, the important line is `app.MapSignalR();`